# How to get filename of a opened file?

Tags: perl

I have this simple script that I'm working on. I must admit, I'm totally new to PERL and kinda stuck with this stupid problem.

```
open(IN, "<def/t.html") or die();
while(<IN>) {
    chomp;
    if($_ =~ m/FF0000/) {
        print "\n".$_."\n";
    }
}
```

So... I opened the t.html and found the given string in the file. Output was ok, but I need also filename of a file in which string was found, to be printed. I really don't know how to return this, and I need it right after the `$_`. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: The filename is "t.html". What's the problem?

Comment: I can see it in the code. This is just a simple example. The  problem will occur, when I check a number of files within a loop. In that case I wouldn't know that. I would only have a few snippets of file content without the filename, in which script founded the given string.

Comment: You mean t.html? Assuming this value is stored on a variable $temp you can do the following: my $index = index($temp, '/'); $temp = substr($temp, $index+1); EDIT: I read your comment now, I don't know what you mean, can you post the code with the loop please? If you're looking through a file list how can you not have their name?

Comment: Then how are you opening the files if you don't know the filenames? You seem to have simplified the problem so much that it went away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a strange idea, but you can if you want:

```
$ cat 1.pl

#somewhere in the code
open(F, "f.txt");
my $f = fileno(F);

#here you want to find the filename
open(FILENAME, "ls -l /proc/$$/fd/$f|");
my @fn = split(/\s+/, <FILENAME>);
print $fn[$#fn],"\n";

$ perl 1.pl 
/home/ic/f.txt
```

Here you know only the filedescriptor and find the filename using it.

You can also write it much shorter with `readlink`:

```
open(F, "f.txt");
my $f = fileno(F);

#here you want to find the filename
print readlink("/proc/$$/fd/$f"), "\n";
```

I must note that the file can be already deleted (but it exists still if it is open).

Answer (score 4):

Simply save the file name in a variable before you open it, then go from there:

```
my $filename = 'def/t.html';
open( IN, '<', $filename ) or die $!;
...
print "\n$filename: " . $_ . "\n";
```

Notice that the above uses the 3-arg form of `open()`, which is safer.

(Also, the language is "Perl", not "PERL".)

Comment: The same idea, but elegant: [IO::File::WithPath](http://p3rl.org/IO::File::WithPath), [IO::File::WithFilename](http://p3rl.org/IO::File::WithFilename) - the objects carry around the original file name